# Build BizTalk Project with Azure DevOps Build Pipeline

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, biztalk, azure-pipelines, biztalk-2016

I've got a Visual Studio Solution which contains only BizTalk projects. These has the following settings.

- BizTalk Server 2016
- .NET Framework 4.6

On the server is installed.

- BizTalk Developer 2016 (only the Project Build Components)
- Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 with .NET 4.5.2 and 4.6 targeting pack

In my Azure DevOps Build Pipeline the build fails with the following error

```
##[error]CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'C:\VSTS_Agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.144.2\_work\1\s\MyProject\MySchema.xsd.cs' could not be found.
```

If I'm searching for this error there are some hits. But I couldn't find something that helps for this problem. Is something missing that have also to be installed or configured?

Comment: what source code repository you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you have committed *.xsd.cs files into your source code tracker. Try to remove them from your repos and build again it should work